Не запускается телеграмм бот, ошибок нет, но он просто не работает
Создаю для школьного проекта простенький бот, который будет собирать инфу о климате в кабинетах. Пока что на начальной стадии, создаю первую кнокпу и первую команду /start, хочу проверить уже, а он никак не запускается. Ошибок не выводит в консоль, но на команду не реагирует.

Работаю на Windows 10 pro
Программа Pycharm
Python 3.12
Библиотека pyTelegarmbotAPI

вот сам код:
import telebot
from telebot import types

bot = telebot.TeleBot("*************************")


@bot.message_handler(commsnds=['start'])
def main(message):
    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    btn1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Столовая', callback_data="kb1")
    markup.row(btn1)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Здравствуйте, состояние климата какого кабинета вы хотите узнать?")


bot.polling(non_stop=True)


Я пробовала:

Создать новый бот с новым токеном
Менять местами строки в функции
Переустанавливать библиотеку
Перезагрузила ноутбук

В идеале я ожидаю работу бота через телеграмм

У тебя в строчке
@bot.message_handler(commsnds=['start'])

Ошибка, надо commsnds исправить на commands, должно заработать))

боже, я не заметила, попробую
